# How to write a zip file using Haskell LibZip?

Tags: haskell, zip

I'm trying to figure out a dead-simple task using [LibZip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LibZip-0.2.0.3/docs/Codec-Archive-LibZip.html) in Haskell: how do I open an archive `foo.zip`, decompress it, recompress it, and save it to a new archive `bar.zip`? With the [Zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-archive-0.1.3.4/docs/Codec-Archive-Zip.html) library, this is easy:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Codec.Archive.Zip (toArchive, fromArchive)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import System.Environment

saveZipAs :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO () 
saveZipAs source dest = do
    arch <- fmap toArchive $ B.readFile source
    putStrLn "Archive info: " >> print arch
    B.writeFile dest $ fromArchive arch
```

LibZip, on the other hand, provides no clear way to do this (that I can see). It only seems to be able to instantiate a zip file with `withArchive` (which is an issue in and of itself, because a file you want to open might not be on disk), and I don't see a way to do any kind of "save as" operation, nor to extract the compressed bytes as a `ByteString` or otherwise (as in Zip). LibZip is supposedly faster than Zip, so I want to at least give it a try, but it seems much more obscure (and also impure, carrying around an `IO` everywhere it goes, where it is really only needed at the beginning and the end, if ever). Can anyone give me some tips?

Side note: it really boggles the mind how people can spend such huge amounts of time writing a library, only to document it so poorly that no one can use it. Library writers, please don't do this!

Comment: Tip: If you want to check others versions of a package, press `contents` on the top right of the page. Then you have the list with multiple package versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link is somehow to an old version of the library, and the very last version of the library seems to have haddock compilation bugs.

Here are file reading functions in a newer version:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/LibZip-0.10.2/docs/Codec-Archive-LibZip.html#g:3

The reverse process seems to be `addFile`/`sourceBuffer` and related functions.

Here is full source code of zip repacking:

```
import Codec.Archive.LibZip
import Codec.Archive.LibZip.Types

main = readZip "foo.zip" >>= writeZip "bar.zip"

readZip :: FilePath -> IO [(FilePath, ZipSource)]
readZip zipName = withArchive [] zipName $ do
        nn <- fileNames []
        ss <- mapM (\n -> sourceFile n 0 (-1)) nn
        return $ zip nn ss

writeZip :: FilePath -> [(FilePath, ZipSource)] -> IO ()
writeZip zipName zipContent = withArchive [CreateFlag] zipName $ do
        mapM_ (uncurry addFile) zipContent
```

Few refactorings still can be done: `liftM2 zip` can be used in `readZip`, and function composition `.` in `writeZip`.

Comment: I don't think that's right -- although I could be wrong. The description of the second argument in `fromFile` says it's the name of the file in the archive. `sourceFile` looks promising, except that it doesn't return an `IO`, so it can't be easily used inside of `main` (possibly some kind of monad transformer gymnastics are required?). Also it really isn't clear just what a "source file" is anyway... Also, `addFile` seems to be for adding a file from the filesystem to the archive, which I'll need eventually but not right now. I'm not sure what `sourceBuffer` is even supposed to do. Blargh.

Comment: By the way, my frustration is only with the quality of documentation, not your help, which I greatly appreciate. :)

Comment: Added full source of the dead-simple task.

Comment: Bravo! That's definitely a touch above my current skill level. Maybe you should write some documentation! :)